# Django, Python: Bulk create for several dependencies

Tags: python, django

I have a lot of dependencies (`Group->Link->Match`) - and I can not create a new one object without a id for `ForeignKey`.

There is method is to simplify or speed up this operation?
Can I create a large object that saves required dependencies? I try to do it via `bulk_create` - but same problem with id.

```
    groups = template.get('groups')
    allMatchObjs = []
    if groups:
        for group in groups:
            groupObj = Group.objects.create(name=group['name'])
            links = group.get('links')
            if links:
                for link in links:
                    linkObj = Link.objects.create(
                        group=groupObj, 
                        name=link['name']
                    matches = link.get('matches')
                    if matches:
                        matchObjs = (Match(
                                        name=match['name'],
                                        link=linkObj) for match in matches)
                        allMatchObjs.extend(matchObjs)

    Match.objects.bulk_create(allMatchObjs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how many elements you have at each level, this may provide some speed up:

```
groups = template.get('groups')
allMatchObjs = []
if groups:
    group_models = [
        Group(name=group['name']
        for group in groups
    ]
    Group.objects.bulk_create(new_groups)

    for g, g_model in zip(groups, group_models):
        links = g.get('links')
        if links:
            link_models = [
                Link(group=g_model, name=link['name'])
                for link in links
            ]
            Link.objects.bulk_create(link_models)

            for l, l_model in zip(links, link_models)
                matches = link.get('matches')
                if matches:
                    matchObjs = [
                        Match(name=match['name'], link=l_model)
                        for match in matches
                    ]
                    allMatchObjs.extend(matchObjs)

Match.objects.bulk_create(allMatchObjs)
```

So you would be using `bulk_create` at each level, although not in a single batch for the intermediate levels.

**UPDATE**

Even better:

```
groups = template.get('groups')

if groups:
    allGroups = [
        Group(name=group['name']
        for group in groups
    ]

Group.objects.bulk_create(allGroups)

allLinks = []
zipped_links = []
for g, g_model in zip(groups, allGroups):
    links = g.get('links')
    if links:
        link_objs = [
            Link(group=g_model, name=link['name'])
            for link in links
        ]

        allLinks.extend(link_objs)

        zipped_links.extend(zip(links, link_objs))

Link.objects.bulk_create(allLinks)                

allMatchObjs = []
for link, l_model in zipped_links:
    matches = link.get('matches')
    if matches:
        matchObjs = [
            Match(name=match['name'], link=l_model)
            for match in matches
        ]
        allMatchObjs.extend(matchObjs)

Match.objects.bulk_create(allMatchObjs)
```

Now you are really using one bulk_create for each level.

Comment: in allGroups no objects with id

Comment: @Lola That may depend on your database. With PostgreSQL and Django 2.0 at least, `bulk_create` will fill back the ids into allGroups.

See this changelog: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/releases/1.10/#database-backends

Which means this feature has been available since Django 1.10.